# How to mock mongodb in rspec (beginner)

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rspec, mongoid

I am an old programmer, but new to ruby, and thrown into an existing code base where I need to extend an rspec test.

The code that needs to be tested uses MongoDB (mongoid), and has a pattern similar to this:

```
 objects = Database::MyTable.active.where(object_id: object_id).to_a
```

I want my rspec code to provide the `objects` hard-coded in the test. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you considered using database fixtures, instead of complicating your rspec tests? In rails the pattern is to have a separate database for testing, with seeded database fixtures.

Comment: Seems like a better approach but I am constrained by prior art.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the "chain" of methods, stubbing is a little awkward, but it can be done.

```rb
allow(Database::MyTable).to(
 receive(:active).and_return(double(
   where: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] 
 ))
)
```

We have stubbed `active` to return a mock (a `double`) on which we stub `where`.

Docs: [rspec-mocks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs)

PS: There are many other ways to write these stubs, some objectively better, some subjectively better. There are also ways to refactor your code to make stubbing easier.

PPS: Welcome to ruby!

Comment: This works! Now I know about `double` to mock data. Also, I found factory_bot, and between these two solutions I have a pretty tidy test.

Comment: Yeah, we use `factory_bot` on all our rails projects. Sounds like you've made a good start :)

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the code that retrieves the data (including the line you mentioned) into one method and the code that consumes/operates on the data into another method, then mock the entire retrieval method. This way you don't need to muck with the exact queries used.